# Python - Using function in parent from child

Tags: python, python-3.x

<strike>I am trying to make a module that when imported can be used to easily define commands for an interactive 'console'. However this requires me to be able to run a function from the parent file, which when I do so I get this: `<function Test at 0x027234B0>` instead of the function being run.</strike>

I am somewhat new to using classes and modules in python so I am not sure what I am meant to be doing.

Here is the module for the Menu (Menu.py): (Not complete, just trying to get this working)

I have just an imbecile and forgot to put the thing in quotes

```py
class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp=0
        self.menuobj = dict()

    def add(self, command, function):
        self.menuobj[command] = function
        print(command)
        return 0

    def debug(self):
        print(self.menuobj)

    def lookup(self, command):
        return self.menuobj[command]

    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            x = input("> ")
            try:
                self.menuobj[x]()

            except KeyError:
                print("Not Found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This module is meant to be imported")
```

And the module that calls it:

```py
import Menu
def Men():
    a = Menu.Menu()
    a.add("1",Test)
    a.mainloop()

def Test():
    print(Test)

Men()
```

Comment: Why would you expect anything other than the function itself? Just look at `Test`, it makes no sense at all.

Comment: What did you *expect* `print(Test)` to output? `Test` resolves to the function object, so your output is entirely expected.

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned below, I've been trying to do this for over an hour and never thought to check this, so it certainly makes me feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `Test()` function, not that its not getting called -

```
def Test():
    print(Test)
```

You are printing the reference to `Test` itself, hence it prints what you get - `<function Test at 0x027234B0>` .

Example to show this -

```
>>> def a():
...     print(a)
...
>>> a()
<function a at 0x0018B198>
```

You should print something meaningful.

Comment: Thank you! I certainly feel like an idiot, I've been stearing at this for over an hour trying to get it to work, and never thought to check that. Must be one of those days.